# picasa web api getting unlisted albums with authkey

Tags: picasa

I am trying to get my unlisted albums using the picasa web api. The FAQs say

> **Can I get unlisted albums through the API?** 
>   The API supports the same
>   authentication tokens as the rest of Picasa Web Albums. If you have
>   the authkey for an unlisted album, you can make a query for that album
>   through the API with that authkey. Otherwise, you can only see
>   unlisted content if you are logged in as the owner of the content.

However when I try

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userid?authkey=aweWEawaDw63453AW
```

It is only listing my public albums. Am I providing the authkey the right way?

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userid?kind=album&authKey=aweWEawaDw63453AW